# Trouble adding text to screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this code, I get the error "ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)".

```
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
welcomeScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

welcomeScreen.fill(white, rect = None, special_flags = 0)

welcomeMessageBackground = pygame.draw.rect(welcomeScreen, red, [200, 100, 400, 75]) 
welcomeFont = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
welcomeMessage = welcomeFont.render('Welcome! Click a button to get started.', True, white)
pygame.Surface.blit(pygame.Surface(display_width, display_height), welcomeMessageBackground, area = None, special_flags = 0)
pygame.display.update()
```

The line causing problems is

```
pygame.Surface.blit(pygame.Surface(display_width, display_height), welcomeMessageBackground, area = None, special_flags = 0)
```

I've tried substituting the variables for the values 800 and 600, same error. What I want is for the text in welcomeMessage to appear over the rect welcomeMessageBackground. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't make sense.

```
pygame.Surface.blit(pygame.Surface(display_width, display_height), welcomeMessageBackground, area = None, special_flags = 0)
```

You shouldn't call `pygame.Surface.blit()` but the blit method of the surface onto which you want to blit the other surface, e.g.:

```
welcomeScreen.blit(welcomeMessage, (70, 100))
```

`welcomeFont.render` returns a surface which you can blit onto the screen or another surface.

---

To create a `pygame.Surface` instance, you have to pass a tuple for the width and height, `pygame.Surface((100, 200))`, but in your case you don't have to create another surface at all.

---

Also, if you want to add a background color behind the text, you can just pass the color to the `render` method of your font:

```
welcomeMessage = welcomeFont.render(
    'Welcome! Click a button to get started.', True, white, red)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `tuple` for the value:

```
pygame.Surface.blit(pygame.Surface((display_width, display_height)), welcomeMessageBackground, area = None, special_flags = 0)
```

So wrapping your `display_width` and `display_height` inside `()` should work. Check it out the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).